# How Join this tables in MySQL to make a relational query?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm following this perfect place when I have doubts in developing.

I have the following problem:

I'm developing an application where the database was configured like the image:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/iztvr2865/]

Tables like `orgbarriers`, `orggeographs`, `orgrpds` was created for save the relation between id of organization and id of barriers, geographical scopes and roles.

Now, I need to `JOIN` all the related tables but I haven't any ideas about how I can make this.

Also, I don't know if I've make the tables correctly. What I need is: assign to organizations -> barriers, roles, and geographical scopes and then, show the information of each organization with 'joined' information.

Here the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc5f8

I need to know how I can obtain all the relationed tables in one or if it possible.

Comment: What *is* your question?

Comment: use of mongodb or other nosql engines are far more better.

Comment: My question is how i can join all the tables and get assigned barriers, etc for each organization!

Comment: Are you sure that users->organizations have one to many relations? one user can own/manage many organizations?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alex .. 
This application must be multiuser.
But, every user will load lot of organizations, barriers, geographical scopes, roles in development
I've assigned IdUser to organizations to separate the information.

In other words, each user will load lot of organizations, and each organization have the idUser assigned.

I hope you understand me, thank you so much!

Comment: @azure1 not for relational data...

Answer (score 1):

You can start from this query I beleive:

```
SELECT o.*, b.*, g.*
FROM organizations o
LEFT JOIN orgbarriers ob
ON ob.idOrg = o.id
LEFT JOIN barriers b
ON ob.idBarrier = b.id
LEFT JOIN orggeographs og
ON og.idOrg = o.id
LEFT JOIN geographs g
ON og.idGeo = g.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alex. I've tried that way but it seems incorrect because I'm getting NULL values like the image:

http://postimg.org/image/c442aha57/

I don't know why

Comment: @AndrewB you should provide data sample to discuss more. if some of your organization has no relatad records in orgbarriers - that is ok if you see nuuls

Comment: Tell me what you need and I'll be happy to share that ..
Thank you so much!

Comment: @AndrewB I need sample of data for all your tables

Comment: I hope this help you to understand it

Organizations table  http://postimg.org/image/it52463qx/full/
Barriers table http://postimg.org/image/kt13pwljb/
RPD table http://postimg.org/image/srgvmfnjf/
Geographs table http://postimg.org/image/46r7tklb1/
orgbarriers table http://postimg.org/image/cpqafktld/
orgrpds table http://postimg.org/image/s9xnovlp7/
orggeographs table http://postimg.org/image/s9xnovlp7/

Thank you SO MUCH! @Alex

Comment: @AndrewB are you kidding? should I work for you as data entry operator? put it as text into your question, or better create sql fiddle. I don't need to undestand. I am pretty sure that query is ok. the problem is your expectations. so the only thing you should investigate is organization id for those records that you don't like. and then do filter to investigate what is your real data is.

Comment: please sorry! I'm new, I don't want use you as Data entry. Please Sorry!

I will try to put this into a SQL fiddle. 

Thanks and sorry

Comment: Hope this help you! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d7e7

I've deleted some content like users and FOREIGN KEYS because was too large for SQL FIddle

Thank you!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d7e7/1 so as you can see NULLs appear for organization `id = 312` if you check the data set, there is no records with such `idOrg` in `orgbarriers` table. That is why you have your nulls.

Comment: oh yes, It happenned because I've deleted some content in database because fiddle not allow me paste more than 8000!

Comment: so query is ok. just fix the data

Comment: here is fiddle with corrected data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc5f8

Answer (score 1):

@Alex, had just finished this when I saw your answer ;-)

```
select 
    * 
from organizations
    left join orgbarriers on organizations.id = orgbarriers.idOrg
        join barriers on orgbarriers.idBarrier = barriers.id
    left join orggeographs on organizations.id = orggeographs.idOrg
        join geographs on orggeographs.idGeo = geographs.id
    left join orgrpds on organizations.id = orgrpds .idOrg
        join rpd on orgrpds.idRPD = rpd.id
    left join users on organizations.idUser = users.id
```

Comment: Thanks for try to help me!
I've change some incorrect fields name in your query but.. I'm getting empty results..

Corrected query:
select 
    * 
from organizations
    left join orgbarriers on organizations.id = orgbarriers.idOrg
        join barriers on orgbarriers.idBarrier = barriers.id
    left join orggeographs on organizations.id = orggeographs.idOrg
        join geographs on orggeographs.idGeo = geographs.id
    left join orgrpds on organizations.id = orgrpds .idOrg
        join rpd on orgrpds.idRPD = rpd.id
    join users on organizations.idUser = users.id

Comment: try "left join users on organization.idUser = users.id "

Comment: Getting same empty result :(

Comment: is there data in these tables?

Comment: @Andrew: perhaps you can create [a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so as to illustrate your problem? Responses like "same result" or "not working" don't really shed any light on what is happening your end.

Comment: @halfer have here an example, hope this help you, 

Thanks all!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d7e7

Comment: @Andrew: it is customary to put into the fiddle the query you are having trouble with, but there is no query here at all. Alex seems to have figured out the problem on his/her answer, anyway.

Comment: @AndrewB - Using the fiddle, corrected the query, get 2 records returned...  3 when I remembered left join on users...

Comment: @halfer the problem of NULL is because i've deleted some organizations before paste it in fiddle because not allow me more than 8000 characters

Comment: @halfer here fiddle with corrected data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc5f8